# Parallax scrolling with swiper

Tags: html, css, angular, swiper.js

I'm using Angular with idangerous swiper(http://idangero.us/swiper/). My goal is to achieve following behaviour: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp

I tried to use it as in article:

```
<div class="container">
  <swiper [config]="config">
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url('../../assets/images/item1.jpg')"></div>
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url('../../assets/images/item2.jpg')"></div>
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url('../../assets/images/item3.jpg')"></div>
  </swiper>
</div>
```

CSS file:

```
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;

  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Configuration of swiper:

```
config: Object = {
    autoplay: {
      delay: 10000,
      disableOnInteraction: false,
    },
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
      type: 'bullets',
    },
    effect: "fade",
    speed: 2000,
    parallax: true,
  };
```

Unfortunatelly, adding background-attachment: fixed; seems to destroy behaviour of swiper - it always show only first image, even after clicking pagination. Is it forbidden to use this attribute in swiper? Are there any other options to do parallax scrolling that will work in this example?

Answer (score 3):

I's sure yoou got it fixed but here is a sample code for future use
https://jsfiddle.net/c7u5eyrx/
`

```
.swiper-slide {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50%;
    min-height: 80vh;
}

.swiper-container{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:-10;
}

.explain{
  margin-top:80vh;
  background-color:#fff;
}
```

`